# Nlog Config Inside app.config file As Embedded Resource

Tags: c#, app-config, nlog, embedded-resource

I Have a console app that uses nlog for some logging, I have set the config inside the app.config file which works until I set the app.config file as an embedded Resource, Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to manually read the nlog-config-xml, and then assign to XmlLoggingConfiguration. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading